# How to sort list depending on values in sublists?

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I have a list that looks something like this:

```
example = [['b',1],['b',2],['a',2]]
```

And it needs to be sorted to become:

```
example = [['b',1],['a',2],['b',2]]
```

I.e. sorted numerically by the number in the [1] position. The program needs to recognise when there are two numbers that are the same, and then sort these elements alphabetically.

Any ideas?

Edit:

and how would I go about sorting the list so that the highest number is printed first?, i.e:

```
example = [['a',2],['b',2],['b',1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a neat trick

```
>>> example = [['b',1],['b',2],['a',2]]
>>> sorted(example, key=sorted)
[['b', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2]]
```

Only works for Python2 though

---

There are two ways to sort by numbers from highest to lowest

```
>>> sorted(example, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['b', 1]]
```

or

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(sorted(example), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['b', 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), its [key function](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#key-function), and [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> example = [['b',1],['b',2],['a',2]]
>>> example.sort(key=itemgetter(1,0))
>>> example
[['b', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2]]
>>>
```

---

You could also use a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) instead of `operator.itemgetter`:

```
example.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

but that would be slower.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Lets say I now wanted to sort the list from the highest number to the lowest (but still sorting elements with the same number alphabetically a-z), how would you change this code to allow for that?

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas, I've got examples for that in my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> lis = [['b',1],['b',2],['a',2]]
>>> sorted(lis, key=lambda x:x[::-1])
[['b', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2]]
```

To sort the list in-place use `lis.sort(...)`.

Comment: In Python 2.x, we can simply do `print(sorted(lis, key=sorted))` :)