# Python sorting number only according to their first index?

Tags: python, sorting

So earlier I asked this question: [How to sort list depending on values in sublists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718817/how-to-sort-list-depending-on-values-in-sublists/21718855?noredirect=1#comment32843100_21718855)
I wanted to know how to sort some sublists, and I am using this solution:

```
example = (sorted(sorted(example), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

But now I am noticing that this is not sorting the numbers quite correctly, e.g. `25, 43 23, 3` is being sorted as `43, 3, 25, 23`. Obviously 3 is not greater than 25! So how do I change this to check for the whole number? Not just the first place holder.

Comment: Please give proper examples and linking other question will not make this question complete, I believe.

Comment: Convert the strings to integers before comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `example` is a list of strings, so you need to sort by the `int` of the values:

```
example.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

I'm not sure what the nested `sorted`s were for. I took those out.

I also changed `sorted` to `sort`, since you were reassigning to the same variable name. If the list is referenced elsewhere by a different name, you had the right approach. Otherwise this will have somewhat lower overhead.